# Resizing a subreport in SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

We have many subreports created that we wanted to compile into a larger report that can be run and printed as one document.

These subreports created get used individually so they have been sized as such, but in the main report they seem to be too large.  Changing the size of the subreport element doesn't seem to stop the subreport from growing to its actual size.  If I change the actual subreport to be smaller the main report shows it smaller.  But this is seemingly impossible for 2 reasons: there are too many reports, and these reports get used individually so making them small would ruin it in certain situations.

Is there a way to make the size of the subreport equal to the size we set for it rather than the original size?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach,

1) Add a Table

2) Place each subreport in its own table cell

3) Organize cells for desired layout if you dont want it to grow beyond its given size then set `CanGrow` to the `false`.

Comment: I tried this, but it seems the CanGrow property auto changes to true after putting a subreport into it.  I noticed this by first setting the CanGrow to False putting the subreport in and then taking it out and seeing that the CanGrow property reverted to true.  Once you put the subreport in the cell you lose the ability to select the cell itself either from clicking or the properties dropdown.  The result ends up being if the subreport was 5 inches it tries to use up 5 inches of space on the page.  I have also tried this using a rectangle as a container, but that also did not work.